QGC and ROS brigde
I want know is there any brigde between ROS node and QGC application.
For example

The communication like above pic. As you can see, there is no PX4 or others hardware. if it is possible, I don't even want to use mavlink protocol（it seems like QGC use mavlink）.
All I want to do is:

launch QGC app
launch Brigde node
launch ROS nodes

then use QGC send command, like planner or other mission. and the ROS nodes give back the status, That's all.
So, is there any doc or example to achive? Thanks.
